# Compare two images for equality (cross domain)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm looking for a way to check whether a specific image has been loaded on a webpage with Selenium IDE.

My first try was to generate a hash value of the image but this doesn't seem to be possible with javascript. I then found out that you can base64 encode an image if you load it into a canvas and then call toDataUrl(). However this doesn't work if the image is located on another domain.

My image server provides a standard "image not found"-image. I want to check if a specific image was successfully loaded by comparing the loaded image against the failure image. Do you have any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: You need server-side scripting for page scraping.

Comment: Are you absolutely bound to Selenium IDE and Javascript? This is a rather complicated thing IDE wasn't made for (see "Which part of Selenium is appropriate for me?" on http://seleniumhq.org/). It could be done in a stronger language with the use of Selenium 2 (`WebDriver`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at 'selenium signature' as a plug in to the ide? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-signature/

It will make a crc32 signature of the element like *html=50D5FBD3*css=5BBF6784*img=81AD9F9D*
You'll only need the ****img=81AD9F9D**** portion to validate an image.

Comment: Great find! Exactly what I was looking for.